# Python Pip is broken

Tags: manjaro, python3, software-updates, pip

I just did a system update on Manjaro and my python pip is now broken. I was trying to install some stuff for some school projects. It seems to rely on a module called 'six'.
Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3.7", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967428/importerror-no-module-named-six

Answer (score 1):

I had the error myself. After I reinstalled it via python, it works correctly. To do this, proceed as follow:

Download it: `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
and than start: `sudo python get-pip.py`

After that it should work again.

Comment: worked like a charm after this and `sudo pip3 uninstall setuptools`